# Featured Images link to post parent

Tags: posts, images, links

I want to reuse featured images for new posts. So a single featured image from the media library is attached to more than one post. When i use post_parent ); ?> on the attachment page to go back to the post, the user will be redirected to the first post the image was attached.

How can i redirect the user to the actual post the user comes from?

Answer (score 0):

You might use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` but take in mind that is not always sent so check for its existence and think about a fallback!